# update many with a nested document

Tags: mongodb

guys i have an collection called inventory , and i want to update its documents with a nested document

as it should add a document called  **date** with nested documents with **prod date** and **ex date**

the code as follows

```
db.inventroy.updateMany({}, {$set: {dates: { prod date : "14012020" , ex date : "21012020"}}})
```

the below error is clear , but i can n't determine where is exactly the missing : as per the error
2020-01-14T13:00:24.504+0200 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: missing : after prope
rty id :
@(shell):1:50

i would be greetfull if you correct my understanding if any thing was wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problems are in spaces inside `prod date` and `ex date`.

You can try this if you need those spaces:

```
db.inventroy.updateMany({}, {'$set': {dates: {"prod date": "14012020", "ex date": "21012020"}}})
```

But I recommend to change keys: `prod_date` and `ex_date` for example. Cause keys without spaces would be easier to use in the future.

Comment: yes i have added underscore instead of the space and it have worked thanks